# Issue with sharp and strapi

Tags: node.js, strapi, sharp

I just upgraded one of my projects that was running fine to the latest version of Strapi, and I got the following error:

```
yarn run v1.22.19
$ strapi develop
Building your admin UI with development configuration...
Admin UI built successfully
Error: Could not load js config file /Users/my_name/backend/node_modules/@strapi/plugin-upload/strapi-server.js: 
Something went wrong installing the "sharp" module
```

I even started a new blank project and got the same error.

I tried to follow the following steps, first

`brew install vips`

and then delete,

- node_modules build
- .cache
- package-lock.json or yarn.lock

Still having the same issue, should I delete node from system completely, and also uninstall node via brew or both and then reinstall.